# Ensure events raised in correct order from outside a critical section

Tags: c#

Cosider the following sample class:

```
class MyClass
{
   private object syncRoot = new object();
   private int value;

   public event Action<int> SomethingOccurred;

   public void UpdateSomething()
   {
      int newValue;
      lock (syncRoot)
      {
          // ... Do some stuff that modifies some state of the object.
         newValue = ++value;
      }

      // How to ensure that raising these events are done in the correct order?
      SomethingOccurred?.Invoke(newValue);
   }
}
```

In the class above, the events may not occur in the same order that the value was updated apparently, since it's done outside of the lock-statement. The question is, what would be the best way to raise these events *outside* of the lock statement, but ensuring that they are raised in the correct order (i.e. in this case producing the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4...)?

The best idea I've come up with is to essetially have a `ConcurrentQueue` or similar to which the values are added, and having a separate thread raise the events based on the values in the queue.  But I would prefer to not have a separate thread allocated just for raising these events.  Is there a smarter way to accomplish this?

Edit:
My first idea was to have a concurrent queue, and use the following code for raising the event:

```
int result;
while (m_events.TryDequeue(out result))
   SomethingOccurred?.Invoke(result);
```

The problem with that of course is that it does not guarantee the order either, since multiple threads would dequeue stuff concurrently and the same problem as before persists basically.

I could place another lock around the event-raising, but this would cause the same undesired blocking as raising the events from inside the lock in the first place.

So is there a lock-free way to guarantee only a single thread is dequeueing and raising events in this case? Or is there another way that is better altogether?

**Edit 2**:

To illustrate a usage, I want to guarantee that the following code would output the sequence 1 through 20 in order:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.SomethingOccurred += (i) =>
{
   Thread.Sleep(100); Console.WriteLine(i);
};

Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 20), i =>
        myClass.UpdateSomething());
```

I don't care if the event handler is called from different threads, but it must not be called concurrently, and it must be called with in the correct order.

The best solution I have so far would be the following which is likely not very efficient use of threading resources:

```
  class MyClass
  {
     private object syncRoot = new object();
     private int value;
     private readonly ConcurrentQueue<int> m_events = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
     private object eventRaiserLock = new object();

     public event Action<int> SomethingOccurred;

     public void UpdateSomething()
     {
        int newValue;
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
           // ... Do some stuff that modifies some state of the object.
           newValue = ++value;
           m_events.Enqueue(newValue);
        }

        // How to ensure that raising these events are done in the correct order?
        RaiseEvents();
     }

     private void RaiseEvents()
     {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
           lock (eventRaiserLock)
           {
              int result;
              while (m_events.TryDequeue(out result))
                 SomethingOccurred?.Invoke(result);
           }
        });
     }
  }
```

Comment: So you're saying that you have multiple threads running the `UpdateSomething` method and you want to ensure that the events are called in sequence **across** all of the threads?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  (I think, if I understand you correctly)... I want to guarantee that in the example above a subscriber is guaranteed to get the events in order, eg. 1, 2, 3, 4,..., even when multiple threads concurrently are calling `UpdateSomething`. And preferrably without having to have an additional thread for generating the events.

Comment: The calling thread is not the thread getting notified, the subscriber of the event is who is getting notified. And yes, whoever gets the lock first should generate the event first. Look at it as a state-update method, and the sequence of state changes must be captured in the correct order by some subscriber.

Comment: The newValue might have been updated by another thread even before you  raise the event from another thread which thinks it still has its newValue which may not be.You would need to lock around the raise event to ensure its is the correct newValue for the current thread.

Comment: @DeCaf - You would need to use locking or show us how `UpdateSomething` is being called for us to suggest an alternative to locking.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've updated the question with an example usage (and a working solution that doesn't feel very efficient)

Comment: @DeCaf - What is it that you're really trying to do here. Your problem as it stands seems to be a bit abstract.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hard to describe briefly. But I have a class with two methods, ReportError() and ReportSuccess(), and this class *may* update its state when these methods are called depending on the sequence and timing under which they are called. And whenever the state is updated I want an event generated... But I realize now that I can't really generate the event from the same thread calling the method since I want to avoid blocking the callers... meaning I probably really need to just post the events to a SynchronizationContext (or similar) construct.

Comment: @DeCaf - But that doesn't explain why you need the events to be in order.

Comment: @DeCaf - Are you trying to asynchronously trying to do processing yet marry up results to inputs?

Comment: @Enigmativity I need them to be in order because they indicate state transitions, and if they don't occur in order it may indicate an incorrect state transition which would cause the system to react in the wrong way.

Comment: @Enigmativity Either way, I will solve this problem by queueing the events to a queue or some synchronization context like structure and have them asynchronously emitted from there. Or perhaps using Rx, exposing an IObservable instead.  I get the feeling that this question does not really have a much better answer.

Comment: @DeCaf - I was heading towards suggesting an Rx answer. It's probably far more suited to solve your problem. I just wanted to understand your actual problem better.

Comment: @DeCaf - You'd easily do something like `from n in Observable.Range(1, 2) from r in Observable.Start(() => myClass.UpdateSomething()) select new { n, r };`. That's probably not exactly what you need, but it's close. It's asynchronous and pairs up results with input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need ordering, you need synchronization - it's that simple.

It's not entirely obvious what you're trying to do here - the event you're raising is effectively raised on some random thread. Obviously, that's not going to preserve any ordering, since it's perfectly possible for the events to be running concurrently (since `UpdateSomething` is called from multiple threads).

A queue is a simple solution, and you don't need to waste any extra threads either - however, you might want to think about the ordering of the `UpdateSomething` calls anyway - are you sure the items are going to be queued in the proper order in the first place?

Now, `ConcurrentQueue` is a bit tricky in that it doesn't give you a nice, awaitable interface. One option is to use the Dataflow library - a `BufferBlock` does pretty much what you want. Otherwise, you can write your own asynchronous concurrent queue - though again, doing this well is quite complicated. You could use something like this as a starting point:

```
async Task Main()
{
  var queue = new AsyncConcurrentQueue<int>();
  var task = DequeueAllAsync(queue, i => Console.WriteLine(i));

  queue.Enqueue(1);
  queue.Enqueue(2);
  queue.Enqueue(3);
  queue.Enqueue(4);
  queue.Finish();

  await task;
}

private async Task DequeueAllAsync<T>(AsyncConcurrentQueue<T> queue, Action<T> action)
{
  try
  {
    while (true)
    {
      var value = await queue.TakeAsync(CancellationToken.None);

      action(value);
    }
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
}

public class AsyncConcurrentQueue<T>
{
  private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> _internalQueue;
  private readonly SemaphoreSlim _newItem;
  private int _isFinished;

  public AsyncConcurrentQueue()
  {
    _internalQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    _newItem = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
  }

  public void Enqueue(T value)
  {
    _internalQueue.Enqueue(value);
    _newItem.Release();
  }

  public void Finish()
  {
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref _isFinished, 1);
    _newItem.Release();
  }

  public async Task<T> TakeAsync(CancellationToken token)
  {
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      await _newItem.WaitAsync(token);

      token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

      T result;
      if (_internalQueue.TryDequeue(out result))
      {
        return result;
      }

      Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();

      if (_isFinished == 1) throw new OperationCanceledException();
    }

    throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
  }
}
```

This ensures that you have a queue with a global ordering that you can keep filling, and which is emptied continually whenever there are any items. The removal (and execution of the action) is in order of adding, and it happens on a single worker thread. When there are no items to dequeue, that thread is returned to the thread pool, so you're not wasting a thread blocking.

Again, this is still a relatively naïve solution. You want to add more error handling at the very least (according to your needs - e.g. perhaps the `action(value)` call should be in a try-catch so that a failed action doesn't stop your dequeue loop?).

Comment: You are of course correct in that I can't generate events from random threads since I don't want the events generated concurrently.  I could probably Post them to a SynchronizationContext or similar from within the lock to get the desired behavior (which is conceptually similar to the AsyncQueue you posted above).

Comment: @DeCaf Yup, that's the most basic interface, really. Though of course, a `SynchronizationContext` doesn't necessarily imply a non-concurrent execution - the default one simply posts the messages to a thread pool, allowing them to run concurrently (with the `Send` running the delegate directly, again allowing concurrent execution).

Comment: yes, when I said SynchronizationContext I was referring to the concept of a single-threaded dito, rather than the actual current SynchronizationContext of the application. Your async-queue would suffice as well, as long as I had a single (logical) thread dequeuing items from it.

Comment: @DeCaf That's what the `DequeueAllAsync` method does - and without wasting a thread blocking (you should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the `await queue.TakeAsync`; and anywhere else the original context isn't needed, really. Unless you want to raise the event on the UI thread, of course). If you add some error handling, you don't even need to await it - the await is really only there to allow you to gracefully shutdown your application when everything is done.